# Can an Android View's id be safely shared across multiple Activities?

Tags: android, inheritance, layout, view, ambiguity

Say I have two Activities in an Android application, `EditPerson` and `EditEmployee`.

It would seem natural to have the `EditPerson` Activity be a base class for the `EditEmployee` Activity and define methods that marshal data to and from the Views defined in the layout. The `EditPerson` Activity's implementation would push (for example) the "Name" field to and from an `EditText` element. The `EditEmployee` versions would call the base class version, and then marshal its own specialized fields (say a tax id, etc.).

To facilitate the shared code, both activities would have to have a layout resource that defines one or more pairs of `EditText` elements that share the same id. i.e. in `layout\edit_person.xml` there would be:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/name_editor" />
```

And then in `layout\edit_employee.xml`there would be something like:

```
<EditText android:id="@+id/name_editor" />
<EditText android:id="@+id/tax_id_editor" />
<!-- etc. -->
```

Since the "Employee" is a "Person", and there are fields in common (marshaled via inheritance), it would seem as if the id assigned ("name_editor" in the above example) only has to be unique within the scope of an activity (or layout?).

From my testing, this appears to work, but I am paranoid that there would be a unintentional side effect to this approach and use of ambiguous layout element ids. Can anyone confirm that this is a safe practice and/or point out how it will eventually blow up my application? Has anyone ever done similar things?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's common and ok to use. Especially intended when you want to reuse code/classes, but use different layouts.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your experience. Since I am still pretty new in the Android world, it is sometimes harder to get a sense of what is a sane approach.